# Change mouse settings via terminal

Tags: terminal, mouse, monterey

I want to reverse the scroll for my USB (Microsoft) mouse on MacOS Monterey. It works fine but the scroll wheel is backwards, and the tracking speed is slow.
When I go to `System Preference` I see

> Wait for a Bluetooth mouse to be discovered or connect a USB mouse.
>
> No mouse found.

... so evidently my mouse is not detected or recognised.

Another question ([Change mouse speed in terminal without restarting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/333893/252755)) suggests changing default settings via `com.apple.mouse` properties, which are checked like `defaults read -g com.apple.mouse.scaling`, but this doesn't seem to exist in modern MacOS.

How can I change this setting for my mouse? Do I need a new mouse, and if so which (non-Apple) mouse models will be supported?

Comment: Since you don't indicate which model of mouse you have, did you install any software from Microsoft for the mouse? That may have a way to "flip" the scroll wheel.

Comment: I have not; it's just a generic mouse and I can't find any software from Microsoft that supports it. The best they have is [Mouse and Keyboard Center](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/mouse-and-keyboard-center-download-f5b10905-7887-eedb-2f1c-d0737a36a3b2) but this is a Microsoft / Windows app.

Comment: you can specify the scroll type in system preferences like natural or not. that might do the trick or do you want to do that with terminal only?

Comment: I don't care if it's terminal, but because my mouse "isn't found" by System Preferences I can't change the setting there. I can change settings for trackpad, but this (a) is already how I want it, and (b) is not connected / related to the mouse settings.

Comment: What do you mean by „USB (Microsoft) mouse“ - how is it connected to your Mac? Which model? cabled mice don’t need to register- you should able to follow @Ameya ‘s suggestion and e.g. [change the scroll direction via the mouse preferences](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh29222/mac).

Comment: if it is a bluetooth mouse, reset the bluetooth module from the terminal via _sudo pkill bluetoothd_ (or delete _/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist_ from the Finder). Restart the Mac. Repair the mouse and use the mouse preferences to adjust. BTW. make sure to run the latest version of MacOS Monterey.

Comment: try [USB Overdrive](https://www.usboverdrive.com/) to see wether your mouse will be detected. If your device is not listed in the Status section of the USB Overdrive, it may be handled by another driver that was previously installed - see the USB Overdrive support page on how to remove these.

Comment: Very disappointing while *not at all surprising* that I'm required to buy some 3rd party software to support a generic-yet-unblessed mouse on MacOS. Steve Jobs is rubbing his hands together in glee down there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **System Preferences** -> **Mouse**
2. Uncheck the **Scroll direction:Natural** checkbox at the top of the window.
3. Adjust the tracking speed with the sliding bar under **Tracking speed**.

All USB Mouse models should work. If they properly identify themselves as a USB Mouse then it should work.  **If it's not working, try a different mouse.**

Comment: Within the comments of the original question, the user states that the mouse is *not* found in the **System Preferences** so this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I very much love my Logitech MX series mice and keyboards. We use them at work and I choose them personally for my money. We don’t have the issues you mention with Dell or Microsoft mice, though.

The MX 3 is the Cadillac of mice IMO.

- https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/mice/mx-anywhere-3-mac.html

If you’re looking for new hardware - go for Logitech. Software is good (great on Windows), hardware is excellent, Bluetooth and multiple connections superb. If you just want this fixed with your current mouse, go get USB overdrive.

- https://www.usboverdrive.com/

You also can use System Information app to inspect all USB devices. Plug in the mouse and perhaps refresh the listing to check it’s registering as some sort of USB device.

Comment: I loved my Logitech MX as well, until it died after about 18 months of gentle (non-gaming, keyboard-first) use. They aren't cheap so I'm gun shy about going back for more.

Comment: Understood @KirkBroadhurst I’ve edited in using system information to make sure it’s registering on the USB bus. Hopefully it’s not a hardware or cabling issue.

Comment: It shows up as "Microsoft® Comfort Mouse 4500".  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯